# How to validate Token Id before calling any web methods?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am passing the TokenId as Soap Header for all the requests.

```
<soapenv:Header> <tem:TokenIdentity>12345</tem:TokenIdentity>   </soapenv:Header>
```

for example I have 5 webmethods.
I would like that ValidateTokenId() method which shoule be called automatically before accessing any webmethods.

Anybody done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to validate the token

WCF Service implemented(**IDispatchMessageInspector**) the following two methods to take care of Soap header validation and
Logging the SOAP Requests and SOAP Responses.

**AfterReceiveRequest**
So all the incoming SOAP requests are automatically called for ValidateToken() method and will be logged too.

**BeforeSendReply**
All the response SOAP messages are logged here.

```
 #region IDispatchMessageInspector Members
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        int headerIndex1 = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("TokenIdentity", "");
        XmlReader r = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(0).ReadSubtree();
        XElement data = XElement.Load(r);
        var tokenValue = (string)data;

        ValidateToken(tokenValue);

        //Log the Request with Log4Net or something
        //Console.WriteLine("IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest called.");
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
 //Log the Response with Log4Net or something
        //Console.WriteLine("IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply called.");
    }
 #endregion
```